# Вертикальная центровка текста внутри <button>: каким образом это реализует user-agent?

Tags: html, css

Вообщем, делал сегодня кнопочки и задумался: а как происходит центровка текста внутри кнопок, ведь это inline-block элемент. Понятно, что изменив display или line-height, отцентровать текстовое содержимое не сложно. Но вопрос в другом: как это делает user-agent? Я обнулил line-height и padding, проверил все стили и не нашёл причину такого поведения. Текст магическим образом центруется по вертикали внутри inline-block-элемента, или я что-то пропустил?

PS: попробуйте это сделать внутри обычного div с display: inline block, padding: 0 и нулевым line-height у текста.

Comment: А самому тут привести пример своих попыток, сложно было?

Comment: @Air о каких попытках речь? Суть вопроса в том, какие именно попытки сделали разработчики браузеров

Comment: @andreymal, речь о его попытках...  Цитата из  его вопроса - `Вообщем, делал сегодня кнопочки и.....`

Comment: @Air ...и задумался, как устроены браузеры. Так о каких попытках речь-то? У автора нет вопросов с ручной центровкой, цитата из его вопроса — «Понятно, что ... отцентровать текстовое содержимое не сложно»

Comment: Интересная мысль.. А действительно.. Почему же не поделились этой "возможностью"..

Comment: Я всё перепробовал, что только в голову пришло, чтобы отцентровать по вертикали текст внутри inline-block. Но без изменений display, padding и line-height это сделать не получилось. Не вижу смысла приводить примеры неудачных попыток, если найду решение – обязательно поделюсь.

Answer (score 5):

Как насчет такого варианта?

```css
div {
 display: inline-block;
 height: 60px;
 background: #eee;
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
div:before {
 content: "";
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>Test</div>
```

Если же вас волнует вопрос центровки текста по вертикали внутри `<button>`, то, очевидно же, это заложено в самом теге. Так же, как в `<span>` изначально заложен `display:inline` или в `<a>` заложен `cursor:pointer`.

Предыдущий хак может подойти и для переноса текста в верхнюю часть кнопки, однако, нужно быть осторожным с соседними блоками, так как положение может изменится относительно соседей:

```css
button {
 height: 60px;
}
button:before {
 content: "";
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<button>test</button>
```

**UPD**

Если вытащить все свойства, которые превращают кнопку в кнопку, можно почти любой элемент стилизовать визуально:

```css
div {
-apple-color-filter: none;
-webkit-animation-trigger: auto;
-webkit-appearance: button;
-webkit-backdrop-filter: none;
-webkit-backface-visibility: visible;
-webkit-background-clip: border-box;
-webkit-background-composite: source-over;
-webkit-background-origin: padding-box;
-webkit-background-size: auto;
-webkit-border-fit: border;
-webkit-border-horizontal-spacing: 0px;
-webkit-border-image: none;
-webkit-border-vertical-spacing: 0px;
-webkit-box-align: stretch;
-webkit-box-decoration-break: slice;
-webkit-box-direction: normal;
-webkit-box-flex: 0;
-webkit-box-flex-group: 1;
-webkit-box-lines: single;
-webkit-box-ordinal-group: 1;
-webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
-webkit-box-pack: start;
-webkit-box-reflect: none;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
-webkit-clip-path: none;
-webkit-column-axis: auto;
-webkit-column-break-after: auto;
-webkit-column-break-before: auto;
-webkit-column-break-inside: auto;
-webkit-column-progression: normal;
-webkit-cursor-visibility: auto;
-webkit-dashboard-region: ;
-webkit-font-kerning: auto;
-webkit-font-smoothing: auto;
-webkit-hyphenate-character: auto;
-webkit-hyphenate-limit-after: auto;
-webkit-hyphenate-limit-before: auto;
-webkit-hyphenate-limit-lines: no-limit;
-webkit-hyphens: manual;
-webkit-initial-letter: normal;
-webkit-line-align: none;
-webkit-line-box-contain: block inline replaced;
-webkit-line-clamp: none;
-webkit-line-grid: none;
-webkit-line-snap: none;
-webkit-locale: ru;
-webkit-margin-after-collapse: collapse;
-webkit-margin-before-collapse: collapse;
-webkit-marquee-direction: auto;
-webkit-marquee-increment: 6px;
-webkit-marquee-repetition: infinite;
-webkit-marquee-style: scroll;
-webkit-mask-box-image: none;
-webkit-mask-box-image-outset: 0px;
-webkit-mask-box-image-repeat: stretch;
-webkit-mask-box-image-slice: 0 fill;
-webkit-mask-box-image-source: none;
-webkit-mask-box-image-width: auto;
-webkit-mask-clip: border-box;
-webkit-mask-composite: source-over;
-webkit-mask-image: none;
-webkit-mask-origin: border-box;
-webkit-mask-position: 0% 0%;
-webkit-mask-repeat: repeat;
-webkit-mask-size: auto;
-webkit-mask-source-type: alpha;
-webkit-nbsp-mode: normal;
-webkit-print-color-adjust: economy;
-webkit-rtl-ordering: logical;
-webkit-svg-shadow: none;
-webkit-text-combine: none;
-webkit-text-decoration-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.847059);
-webkit-text-decoration-line: none;
-webkit-text-decoration-skip: auto;
-webkit-text-decoration-style: solid;
-webkit-text-decorations-in-effect: none;
-webkit-text-emphasis-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.847059);
-webkit-text-emphasis-position: over right;
-webkit-text-emphasis-style: none;
-webkit-text-fill-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.847059);
-webkit-text-orientation: mixed;
-webkit-text-security: none;
-webkit-text-size-adjust: auto;
-webkit-text-stroke-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.847059);
-webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;
-webkit-text-underline-position: auto;
-webkit-text-zoom: normal;
-webkit-transform-style: flat;
-webkit-user-drag: auto;
-webkit-user-modify: read-only;
-webkit-user-select: text;
align-content: normal;
align-items: flex-start;
align-self: auto;
alignment-baseline: auto;
alt: "";
animation-delay: 0s;
animation-direction: normal;
animation-duration: 0s;
animation-fill-mode: none;
animation-iteration-count: 1;
animation-name: none;
animation-play-state: running;
animation-timing-function: ease;
background-attachment: scroll;
background-blend-mode: normal;
background-clip: border-box;
background-color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
background-image: none;
background-origin: padding-box;
background-position: 0% 0%;
background-repeat: repeat;
background-size: auto;
baseline-shift: baseline;
border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.847059);
border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-style: none;
border-bottom-width: 0px;
border-collapse: separate;
border-image-outset: 0px;
border-image-repeat: stretch;
border-image-slice: 100%;
border-image-source: none;
border-image-width: 1;
border-left-color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
border-left-style: outset;
border-left-width: 2px;
border-right-color: rgb(192, 192, 192);
border-right-style: outset;
border-right-width: 2px;
border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.847059);
border-top-left-radius: 0px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-style: none;
border-top-width: 0px;
bottom: auto;
box-shadow: none;
box-sizing: border-box;
buffered-rendering: auto;
caption-side: top;
caret-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.847059);
clear: none;
clip: auto;
clip-path: none;
clip-rule: nonzero;
color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.847059);
color-interpolation: sRGB;
color-interpolation-filters: linearRGB;
color-rendering: auto;
column-count: auto;
column-fill: balance;
column-gap: normal;
column-rule-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.847059);
column-rule-style: none;
column-rule-width: 0px;
column-span: none;
column-width: auto;
content: ;
counter-increment: none;
counter-reset: none;
cursor: default;
cx: 0px;
cy: 0px;
direction: ltr;
display: inline-block;
dominant-baseline: auto;
empty-cells: show;
fill: rgb(0, 0, 0);
fill-opacity: 1;
fill-rule: nonzero;
filter: none;
flex-basis: auto;
flex-direction: row;
flex-flow: row nowrap;
flex-grow: 0;
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-wrap: nowrap;
float: none;
flood-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
flood-opacity: 1;
font-family: system-ui;
font-optical-sizing: auto;
font-size: 11px;
font-stretch: normal;
font-style: normal;
font-synthesis: style weight small-caps;
font-variant: normal;
font-variant-alternates: normal;
font-variant-caps: normal;
font-variant-east-asian: normal;
font-variant-ligatures: normal;
font-variant-numeric: normal;
font-variant-position: normal;
font-variation-settings: normal;
font-weight: normal;
fullscreen-auto-hide-duration: ;
fullscreen-inset-bottom: ;
fullscreen-inset-left: ;
fullscreen-inset-right: ;
fullscreen-inset-top: ;
glyph-orientation-horizontal: 0deg;
glyph-orientation-vertical: auto;
grid-auto-columns: auto;
grid-auto-flow: row;
grid-auto-rows: auto;
grid-column-end: auto;
grid-column-start: auto;
grid-row-end: auto;
grid-row-start: auto;
grid-template-areas: none;
grid-template-columns: none;
grid-template-rows: none;
hanging-punctuation: none;
height: 18px;
image-rendering: auto;
isolation: auto;
justify-content: normal;
justify-items: normal;
justify-self: auto;
kerning: 0;
left: auto;
letter-spacing: normal;
lighting-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
line-break: auto;
line-height: 13px;
list-style-image: none;
list-style-position: outside;
list-style-type: disc;
margin-bottom: 2px;
margin-left: 2px;
margin-right: 2px;
margin-top: 2px;
marker-end: none;
marker-mid: none;
marker-start: none;
mask: none;
mask-type: luminance;
max-height: none;
max-width: none;
min-height: 15px;
min-width: 0px;
mix-blend-mode: normal;
object-fit: fill;
object-position: 50% 50%;
opacity: 1;
order: 0;
orphans: auto;
outline-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.847059);
outline-offset: 0px;
outline-style: none;
outline-width: 0px;
overflow-wrap: normal;
overflow-x: visible;
overflow-y: visible;
padding-bottom: 3px;
padding-left: 6px;
padding-right: 6px;
padding-top: 2px;
page-break-after: auto;
page-break-before: auto;
page-break-inside: auto;
paint-order: normal;
perspective: none;
perspective-origin: 19.9375px 30px;
place-content: normal normal;
place-items: flex-start normal;
place-self: auto auto;
pointer-events: auto;
position: static;
r: 0px;
resize: none;
right: auto;
row-gap: normal;
rx: 0px;
ry: 0px;
safe-area-inset-bottom: ;
safe-area-inset-left: ;
safe-area-inset-right: ;
safe-area-inset-top: ;
scroll-padding: 0px;
scroll-padding-bottom: 0px;
scroll-padding-left: 0px;
scroll-padding-right: 0px;
scroll-padding-top: 0px;
scroll-snap-align: none none;
scroll-snap-margin: 0px;
scroll-snap-margin-bottom: 0px;
scroll-snap-margin-left: 0px;
scroll-snap-margin-right: 0px;
scroll-snap-margin-top: 0px;
scroll-snap-type: none;
shape-image-threshold: 0;
shape-margin: 0px;
shape-outside: none;
shape-rendering: auto;
speak-as: normal;
stop-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
stop-opacity: 1;
stroke: none;
stroke-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
stroke-dasharray: none;
stroke-dashoffset: 0px;
stroke-linecap: butt;
stroke-linejoin: miter;
stroke-miterlimit: 4;
stroke-opacity: 1;
stroke-width: 1px;
tab-size: 8;
table-layout: auto;
text-align: center;
text-anchor: start;
text-decoration: none;
text-indent: 0px;
text-overflow: clip;
text-rendering: auto;
text-shadow: none;
text-transform: none;
top: auto;
transform: none;
transform-box: border-box;
transform-origin: 19.9375px 30px;
transform-style: flat;
transition-delay: 0s;
transition-duration: 0s;
transition-property: all;
transition-timing-function: ease;
unicode-bidi: normal;
vector-effect: none;
vertical-align: baseline;
visibility: visible;
white-space: normal;
widows: auto;
width: 39.875px;
will-change: auto;
word-break: normal;
word-spacing: 0px;
word-wrap: normal;
writing-mode: horizontal-tb;
x: 0px;
y: 0px;
z-index: auto;
zoom: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>div</div>
```

Но, магическое свойство, перемещающее текст по центру вы не найдете. Если ответить более точно на вопрос "Каким образом это реализует user-agent?", получится примерно следующее: "Написан код, который задает нужные параметры каждому тегу, в том числе и для `<button>`".

Comment: Отличное решение, формально вы условий не нарушили и выполнили центровку. Но увы, это решение равносильно добавлению элемента, хоть и не в документе. Меня как раз интересует вопрос: каким образом заложена такая центровка браузером в инлайн-блок – кнопку. И посему вопрос остаётся открытым.

Comment: @halfPeiceOfGangsta так об этом я и написал. У всех тегов есть изначально заложенные свойства, которые не всегда можно отключить или изменить. В таблице стилей мы лишь дополняем эти свойства. У `<button>`, одни из таких свойств является центровка текста по вертикали. Никаким способом, кроме оборачивания текста в тег или использования flexbox, вы не сможете убрать вертикальное выравнивание. Ну, и кроме представленного выше хака.

Comment: Вопрос был не в том, чтобы что-то добавить или убрать из таблицы стилей, а понять, каким путём именно браузеры выполняют эту центровку. Я прекрасно понимаю, что браузеры применяют стандартные css-свойства для некоторых html-элементов, и в случае с кнопками пересмотрел их все на разных движках, но не нашёл то свойство, благодаря которому происходит центровка, поэтому и возник такой вопрос.

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev, а вот и ответ..
У вас там есть `line-height: 13px`, скорее всего, он и отвечает за центрирование, только высчитывается значение браузером. Проверьте, выставите `height: 60px; line-height: 55px` - текст будет визуально по центру.

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 Спасибо, конечно, за принятый ответ. Но, я уверен, что дело не в `line-height`. И объяснить поведение элемента стандартными стилями нельзя. Задайте кнопке высоту, сделайте фиксированную ширину с несколькими словами и вы увидите, что значение межстрочного интервала не меняется, а текст по центру. Просто у некоторых элементов, есть код, который заложен во все версии user-agent и он никак не связан со стилями. То есть, в браузере нам показывают только те стили, которые можно изменить. Для понимания, попробуйте объяснить внешний вид `select` при помощи одних только стилей user-agent-а.

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev, это-то понятно. Но всё равно интересно, почему это "тайное" свойство не идёт в стандарт.

Answer (score 3):

На примере элемента `<button>` в браузере Chrome - вот как он применяет стили, предопределенные для элементов по умолчанию:

```
/* 1 */
input, textarea, select, button {
    ...
    text-align: start;
    ...
}


/* 2 */
input[type="button" i], input[type="submit" i], input[type="reset" i], 
input[type="file" i]::-webkit-file-upload-button, button {
    ...
    text-align: center;
    ...
}
```

Эти свойства показываются в веб-инспекторе как `user agent stylesheet`. 
А уж какие именно свойства из встроенной таблицы стилей применяются к определенным элементам, определяет свойство `appearance`, то бишь, "внешний вид". Для разных элементов в браузере заданы разные значения этого свойства. Причем его можно переопределить при желании (используя вендорные префиксы, например, `-webkit-appearance`), отчего вид элемента по умолчанию меняется.

---

Добавлено для вертикальной центровки:

На самом деле в `<button>` нет никакой "вертикальной центровки", просто при габаритах и шрифте по умолчанию КАЖЕТСЯ, что она есть.

В инлайн-элементах выравнивание происходит по базовой линии шрифта (`veritical-align:baseline`), а расстояние между ней и прочими линиями у каждого шрифта разное. И от этих линий пляшут габариты элементов. У некоторых шрифтов это приводит к визуальной похожести на вертикально отцентрированный текст.

На скриншоте я вам соорудил несколько кнопок с разными шрифтами и дефолтным расположением. Какая из них, по-вашему, вертикально отцентрирована? ;)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Немного не то. Речь идёт о вертикальном центрирование текста. А горизонтальный, уверен, что делается при помощи `text-align: center;`.

Comment: Понял. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: тогда как объясните [это](https://jsfiddle.net/jgxkdL1n/) :D

Comment: Точно так же. `X = (H - h)/2`, где `H` - заданная вами высота кнопки, `h` - высота шрифта (кегля, т. е. условного прямоугольника, в который вписана литера), а `X` - расстояние, которое браузер добавляет сверху и снизу. К этому расстоянию либо добавляются паддинги (если `box-sizing:content-box`, по дефолту), либо их соотношение определяет смещение текста по вертикали (в случае `box-sizing:border-box`).